# Running SQL Commands on Sybase Table in C++

Tags: c++, bash, c++14, sybase

**UPDATED WITH MODIFIED CODE IN SCREENSHOTS**

There is a Sybase database setup and the provided isql script works in connecting to it. What I am trying to do now is to be able to connect to the database to run some sql commands on it (using the isql script or not) and storing the output in a data structure for processing each row in c++. I found online a small piece of code that should allow me to run the isql script by passing in the command as a c-style string, but trying to compile the cpp file gives an error of popen and pclose not declared in the scope. If there is another way of connecting to the database or if you know how to resolve that error, please let me know.

Original Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
  char buffer[128];
  std::string result = "";
  std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe( popen(cmd, "r"), pclose());
  if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
  while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL)
      result += buffer;
  }
  return result;
}
```

[Compiling code with GNU++14 in response to ildjarn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkSDj.png)

[Compiling code with lambda function for pipe in response to max66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A99rv.png)

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=gnu++14` instead of `-std=c++14`, and change `pclose()` to `pclose` or `&pclose`.

Comment: Updated with screenshots of the error messages and code

Answer (score 0):

Not declared in the scope?

Are you sure?

My compiler says that `pclose()` needs an argument.

I suggest you to modify the `pipe` declaration using a custom deleter; a simple lambda function should work; something like

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe( popen(cmd, "r"), [](auto ptr) { if ( ptr ) pclose(ptr); });
```

Comment: Yes, I added an image of the compilation error and once again with your lambda function.

Comment: @AndreyChoi - no idea; sorry. My compiler compile your code so I suppose the problem isn't strictly related to it. I see that you use g++; in wich platform (OS, CPU, etc.) ?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
Intel Xeon E5-1603
Using Cygwin 64 bit

Comment: @AndreyChoi - no idea; just a couple of suggestions: (a) try with `_popen()` and `_pclose()` instead of `popen()` and `pclose()` or (b) define `_BSD_SOURCE` before the inclusion of `stdio.h`